# PHP, laravel, why is this query failing on ubuntu?

Tags: php, ubuntu, laravel-5

This works on WAMP just fine:

```
$db = $instance->Databases->where('db_default', 1)->first();
```

It assings perfectly the value of the model im looking for, but it doesnt work on Ubuntu and I have no idea why, after hours of trying and trying, I did this:

```
$db = $instance->Databases->where('db_default', '1')->first();
```

And it worked correctly, is there something wrong with my Ubuntu 14 install or this is standard behavior?  In the laravel docs the query without quotes so I know its possible.

Just in case the db_default field on my database its of type **tinyint**.

Comment: please post the error you are getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I was using Databases without (), the correct way is:

```
$db = $instance->Databases()->where('db_default', 1)->first();
```

My biggest problem was that first I wasnt getting any error (only an empty result on Ubuntu) and that it sure is working on WAMP.

Ill leave this open in case someone can shed light into this issue.